# Binding more than one array to a WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I trying to bind a few arrays into a Wpf datagrid using C#. What i able to do is only bind one array into the datagrid. Does anyone know how to bind more than one array into a datagrid? The code i try below doesn't work. The datagrid show nothing.

My Datagrid code snippet:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDatagrid" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"  Width="60" Binding="{Binding Date}"/> 
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Width="55" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="No" Width="69" Binding="{Binding No}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# code snippet:

```
string[] Date = {"2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012"};
string[] Time={"10:30","10:32","10:35","10:42","10:45"};
int[] No = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = No;
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Date;
MyDataGrid.ItemSource = Time;
```

Comment: Do all of arrays have the same length (it isn't true for your code snippet)?

Comment: sorry, i miss out a data for the time array. Yes, all the array should have the same length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't bind multiple arrays to the same Data Grid; but you can achieve the same end with a class:

```
public class Row
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int No { get; set; }
}
```

Populate using Linq:

```
string[] Date = {"2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012","2-Nov-2012"};
string[] Time={"10:30","10:32","10:35","10:42","10:45"};
int[] No = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Row[] rows = Date.Select( (date, index) => new Row {
    Date = date,
    Time = Time[index],
    No = No[index]
}).ToArray();

MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = rows;
```